# How to make word boundary all elements concat with `|`?

Tags: regex

In this statement, `do Output.printString("THE AVERAGE IS: ");`, `int` matches `int` in `printString`, but if we add `^` at front it will work as expected.

Is there a way to add `^` to all elements in `|`? I'm doing a tokenizer and there are actually many keywords and I don't want to add `^` to each keyword.

[image]

Comment: Use word boundaries `\b` instead of `^` and `$` or surround the alternatives with a group `^(?:a|b|c)` if you want to use the anchor `^`

Comment: `^(word1|word2|wordN)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `^(word1|word2|wordN)` will only match the first token, `class`.

Comment: It does not matter, you just need to group the patterns in order to anchor them at a single common location.

Comment: How can I do that?